# How to derive hypergeometric distribution pmf via ordered sampling?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-distributions, binomial-distribution

So for hypergeometric distribution the set up is as follows. We have $N$ things, $M$ of which are of a type $A$. We pick $n$ things at random without replacement. Let $X$ be the number of things that we pick which are of type $A$. The standard way to derive the probability mass function for X is via unordered sampling without replacement.

I am trying to do this using ordered sampling without replacement instead, but I can't see why the end result should be the same. For my probability $P(X=k)$, I have:

$$P(X=k) = \frac{\frac{M!}{(M-k)!} \times \frac{(N-M)!}{(N-M-n+k)!}}{\frac{N!}{(N-n)!}}$$

and I don't see how this is equal to the standard pmf from unordered sampling approach.

Comment: Your numerator only consider the order among type A and the order among non type A

Comment: I don't understand, how should it be modified? @RezhaAdrianTanuharja

Comment: For example, your numerator does not differentiate between $A_{1}A_{2}A_{3}B_{1}B_{2}$ and $A_{1}B_{1}B_{2}A_{2}A_{3}$ but your denominator does

Comment: So I need to multiply by an $n!$ term in numerator to account for all possible permutations of the $n$ things I picked? But that still doesn't give the correct answer @RezhaAdrianTanuharja

Answer (score 1):

In order to choose an ordered sample of $n$ things which contains exactly $k$ elements of type $A$, you need to

1. Choose which of the $k$ positions in your sample have the type-$A$ objects. There are $\color{red}{\binom nk}$ ways to do this. (This step is missing from the unordered sample version).
2. Fill these $k$ positions with type-$A$ objects. This is done in $\frac{M!}{(M-k)!}$ ways.
3. Fill the remaining $n-k$ positions with type-$B$ objects. This is done in $\frac{(N-M)!}{[(N-M)-(n-k)]!}$ ways.

After dividing by the total number of ordered samples, $\frac{N!}{(N-n)!}$, the probability is
$$
P(X=k) = \frac{\color{red}{\binom nk}\times \frac{M!}{(M-k)!} \times \frac{(N-M)!}{(N-M-n+k)!}}{\frac{N!}{(N-n)!}}
$$
This now agrees with the formula you get from an unordered analysis.

Comment: Thanks. For step 1, why do we not care about the order of the $k$ positions, i.e. why don't we have simply $\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}$ ?   @Mike Earnest

Comment: @Blue_Dynamic The $k$ positions already come with an order, namely left to right. We choose an unordered set of positions in $\binom nk$ ways, then choose an ordered list of type-$A$ elements in $M!/(M-k)!$ ways. Then we put the first chosen element in the leftmost position, the second chosen element in the position to the right of the leftmost one, and so on. The placement of the type-$A$ objects is completely determined by $\binom nk\times M!/(M-k)!$.

Comment: Thank you. Tbh, I am struggling to grasp this idea of ordering in this scenario, but perhaps given time to contemplate, I'll process it @Mike Earnest